# Batch File - Delimiter for multiple spaces

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, delimiter

I'm trying to seperate each token from a txt document that I have, and echo out each word. The problem is that each token has a different amount of spaces between them. For example:

Administrator____________User 1________________Guest

The "_" each represent one space, ex. there are 12 spaces between administrator and user 1 and 16 spaces between user 1 and gues.

How can I use a batch script to echo out each one of these separately if:

1)The file is "C:\Usernames.txt"
2)They are all on the first line of the txt file

I've tried:

```
 FOR /F "delims=" %A IN (C:\Usernames.txt) DO ECHO %A
```

And all I get is "Administrator" echoed. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT:

By throwing a for loop in the for loop I was able to get a little closer. My code was

```
 FOR /F "delims=" %A IN (C:\Usernames.txt) DO FOR %B IN (%A) DO ECHO %B
```

This allowed me to echo it into 4 parts, however I need three. I got:

```
Administrator, User, 1, Guest
```

How can I make it so User and 1 join to be User 1?

Comment: Is the make-up the lines predetermined or random text?

Comment: I'm actually outputting it from the "net user" command into a text file. Then from that text file I am extracting that line which has the users on it to a different text file. And now I'm at this point, where I need to echo (better yet set a variable) to each user on the computer. So your question, its random because it will be different for each computer depending on their users.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What tools deal with spaces in columnar data well?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195851/what-tools-deal-with-spaces-in-columnar-data-well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work: it relies on there being at least two spaces between each username and that no username will contain two consecutive spaces.

```
net user |find "  "|repl " {2,50}" "\r\n" x
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

Comment: This is helping. How can I use this if I have usernames with a space? You said it seems to work as long as there are no two consecutive spaces, but my username only has one and it doesn't work. Its printing out - Administrator, User, 1, Guest

Comment: I changed the regexp - it works in a limited test here.